# Upload a file to Amazon S3 with NodeJS and S3FS/multiparty

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

i am using multiparty and S3FS to upload files to amazon s3 ,when writing a file stream to s3 it creates the temp file path along with bucket path,for example :

```
var S3FS = require('s3fs');
var s3fsImpl = new S3FS('my-bucket/files',{
    accessKeyId: config.amazonS3.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.amazonS3.secretAccessKey
});

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/upload', function (req, resp) {

        // get the file location
        var file = req.files.file;
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);


            return s3fsImpl.writeFile(fileName,stream).then(function(){
                fs.unlink(file.path,function(err){
                    if(err)
                        console.error(err);
                });

                resp.send('done');

            }).catch(function (err) {
                return resp.status(500).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            });

    });
};
```

The file should be written in s3 in path :

my-bucket/files

while now it's writing the temp file path in amazon s3 bucket:

```
my-bucket/files/home/ubuntu/www/html/sampleProject/public/files
```

any idea why temp file path `'home/ubuntu/www/html/sampleProject/public/files'` get created inside s3 bucket when writing the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution myself ,the file name i was sending to write file was wrong , i only replaced `\` with `/` when getting the file name from temp path.

```
var filePath= 'home\ubuntu\www\html\sampleProject\public\files\myfile.jpg'.replace(/\\/g, '/');

var fileName = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/')+1,filePath.length-1)
```

Comment: It is advisable to use the 'path' module to resolve the paths programmatically instead of using replace. This will ensure that it is platform independent. https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths

Comment: thanks  @Sterex , i used path module instead , i was beginner in nodejs at that time :)